# Controller Extension - System.SObjectException

Tags: apex, visualforce

This is my VF Page

```
<apex:page standardController="Expense__c" extensions="myControllerExtension">
 <p/>
    <apex:form >
        <apex:inputField value="{!Expense__c.name}"/> <p/>
        {!all}
        <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller Extension

```
public class myControllerExtension {

    public final Expense__c exp;


    // The extension constructor initializes the private member    // variable acct by using the getRecord method from the standard    // controller.    
    public myControllerExtension(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) 
    {
        this.exp = (Expense__c)stdController.getRecord();
    }

    public String getGreeting() 
    {
        return 'Hello ' + exp.name + ' (' + exp.id + ')';
    }

    public String getAll()
    {
       return ' Id = '+exp.Id+' Name = '+exp.Name+' Type = '+exp.Type__c+' Amount = '+exp.Amount__c;
       }
}
```

I am getting the following runtime exception when rendering this VF page.
I am passing a valid ID value of a Expense__c record like below

```
https://c.ap1.visual.force.com/apex/Extension1?id=a009000001ajXlT
```

The exception is

```
System.SObjectException: SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: Expense__c.Type__c

Class.myControllerExtension.getAll: line 19, column 1
```

I am not able to understand as to why I am getting this exception because "exp" is already instantiated via a constructor (standardcontroller's.getRecords() method) ?.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally, in Apex, if you get an instance of an object using a query, you only have the fields available that you've put in your query. Accessing other fields will result in the exception you got. In the case of an instance of an object you got using the `getRecord()` function of a standard controller, the instance automatically has the fields that you use in the visualforce page available.

In your case, the page contains `{!Expense__c.Name}`, so that's available in the controller. However, your controller also uses `exp.Type__c`. Since your page doesn't contain `{!Expense__c.Type__c}`, it will not be available. There are 2 solutions to this problem, either do a query in the constructor of the controller extension, containing all the fields that you need, or, the one I usually use; put a section of unrendered outputTexts at the bottom of your page with all the fields that you do need in the controller, but not directly on the page, like so: `<apex:outputText value="{!Expense__c.Type__c}" rendered="false" />`

Edit: one additional note regarding unit tests for controller extensions. If you create a page reference in your test, set it as the current page in the test using `Test.setCurrentPage()`, and after that instantiate a standard controller with an instance of an object, you have to query for the fields manually in the test, because they will not get loaded by assigning the page in the test.